# URL Query String to select content

Tags: jquery, query-string

I have a number of pages with lessons listed like this:

```
<div class="et_pb_module">Page Title</div>
<div class="insert-after"></div>
<div class="lesson-container">
   <div class="et_pb_module">
      <div class="content">
        Lesson 1
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="et_pb_module">
      <div class="content">
        Lesson 2
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="et_pb_module">
      <div class="content">
        Lesson 3
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="et_pb_module">
      <div class="content">
        Lesson 4
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

If there is a specific lesson called in the URL's query string I want only that lesson to be shown on the page:

E.g. **`foo.com/lessons?lesson1`** should only show "lesson 1"

I've got an IF statement in jQuery working that does this:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("?lesson1") > -1) {
        $('.et_pb_module').hide();/*Hide all lessons*/
        $('.lesson-container .et_pb_module:nth-of-type(2) .content ').insertAfter('.insert-after'); /*Select content from first lesson and place it at top of the page after 'insert-after'*/
 }
```

This works fine but will involve me having to cut and past the above up to nine times updating the query string and `:nth-of-type` selector each time creating lots of repetitious code.

Is there a way I can use an array to compress this process?

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: So why don't you just use a querystring and have a value that represents the section with a class or id that matches it and show it? `?lesson=lesson1` than read lesson to get the value, than select that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by placing an `id` attribute on the `div` elements which contain the lesson details. From there you can use the `getParameterByName()` function referenced in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/519413) to read the value from the URL and then show the required `div`. Try this:

```html
<div class="et_pb_module">Page Title</div>
<div class="insert-after"></div>
<div class="lesson-container">
  <div class="et_pb_module" id="lesson1">
    <div class="content">Lesson 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="et_pb_module" id="lesson2">
    <div class="content">Lesson 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="et_pb_module" id="lesson3">
    <div class="content">Lesson 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="et_pb_module" id="lesson4">
    <div class="content">Lesson 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
var lesson = getParameterByName('lesson');
if (lesson) {
    $('.lesson-container .et_pb_module').hide();
    $('#' + encodeURIComponent(lesson)).show();
}
```

Note that for this to work the URLs would need to be in this format:

```
foo.com/lessons?lesson=lesson1
```

Comment: This works well, but I'm just wanting the selected lessons content div not the encompassing et_pb_module which is an accordion tab and closed by default. Is there a way to select the lessons content div and append to the top as before?

Comment: Actually I've resolved this question myself. Thanks. One last question. Manually adding lesson ID's is going to take time (this is on many pages). Is there a way to automatically add these?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not strictly an jQuery answer, but the same is possible using CSS:

```css
.lesson {
  display: none;
}
.lesson:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#1">1</a>
<a href="#2">2</a>
<div id="1" class="lesson">
  DIV 1
</div>
<div id="2" class="lesson">
  DIV 2
</div>
```

The `.lesson:taget` becomes active when an div with the id of the current target (so, the anchor link) is available. 
For more info on this see https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/:target